# How does Adobe Dynamic Tag Management detect st.tl variables pushed to the data layer after the DTM scripts have been loaded?

Tags: adobe-analytics

We are looking at using data layer to capture all events, and then have DTM read off of this. It makes sense for the s.t/pageload call - but how does it work with link tracking that get added to the data layer after the DTM scripts have already loaded?

Comment: Just as an FYI, the data layer spec I linked in you other questions also has room for events. You could watch the events array for additions and react accordingly, or preload all applicable event data for that page and call a direct call rule or event based rule to process it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi MaximusDecimusMeridius -

This can be done using a few different methods. The most convenient is to use an event based rule that listens for an action (click, for example) and set your variables with your defined data elements within the rule UI.

The other option is to set your variables within the AA "custom page code" of the rule with JavaScript.

Hope this helps.